# tmux zoom in or out without toggle

Tags: tmux

tmux's zoom (<kbd>< prefix></kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd>
 or `resize-pane -Z`) is a toggle.

How do I zoom out (restore) *only* if the current pane is already zoomed in?

How do I zoom in (maximize) *only* if the current pane is un-zoomed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`tmux-zoom-in.sh`**

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Zoom in the current pane ONLY if it is not currently zoomed.
# Requires tmux version >= 1.8

tmux list-panes -F '#F' | grep -q Z || tmux resize-pane -Z
exit 0
```

**`tmux-zoom-out.sh`**

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Zoom out the current pane ONLY if it is not currently zoomed.
# Requires tmux version >= 1.8

tmux list-panes -F '#F' | grep -q Z && tmux resize-pane -Z
exit 0
```